# parse specific website data and store them in db table

Tags: asp.net, parsing, web

i want to parse a table row(with current name eg.test) from site that requires user/pass and store this in a database table.
Is this possible to be done in asp.net (or asp.net mvc4)?

*i have the username/password
*the site login form is : http://exat.ru/toursearch/

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about web scraping, and ASP.net might not be the best fit for what you are trying.  There are a number of web scraping frameworks out there, e.g.

http://scrapy.org/ for python

or

http://spyderwebtech.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/scraping-websites-with-curl/ using CURL

Comment: thanks for the answer but i must make this project in asp.net

Comment: May I ask why?  It's not the best fit for this requirement (i.e. it is a server side code framework designed to serve responses, rather than to call out to other sites and process them).  If you need to have this running without any user interaction, then it really isn't ideal.

Comment: i say "i must use asp.net" because is simply my boss order :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the 'HttpWebRequest' which can get the site data for you. Although you may have to parse it using a custom solution